# How do I practice Buddhism to attain peace of mind and know the inner self?

Tags: personal-practice, daily-life

I am distracted by the surroundings and at times lose my presence. I think deep down on the perspectives like meaning of life, purpose of life, focus on the one who really are, but get distracted many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [Satipattana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html) and the [Anatta Lakkhana Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.2-Anatta-Lakkhana-S-s22.59-piya-proto.pdf) and do [Satipattana meditation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpzurcpIDeY). Examine the things you consider to be the self and see if they are worth taking as a self. As for the inner self, examine if there's anything inside you that is worth considering as a self.

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to recommend you to look at two books: “The Joy of Living: Unlocking the Secret and Science of Happiness”  by [Yongey Mingyur Rinpoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yongey_Mingyur_Rinpoche) and “[Zen training](http://terebess.hu/zen/mesterek/SekidaTraining.pdf)” by Katsuki Sekida.